# Is it possible to determine the facet content in a custom controls design definition?

Tags: xpages

I'm putting together the design definition for a custom control and would like to vary how it displays based on whether or not a different custom control has been placed in the one of the facet areas. Is this possibe with the design definition and if so, how?

I know I can reference properties of the custom control by using "this", but I couldn't guess as to how to get to the facet content information.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the design definition you can add a callback node where your facet should appear. This should expose the Editable Area when you add your control to another page.

The format for the callback node would look similar to

`<xp:callback id="callbackID" facetName="facetname" />`

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do that, but my question is whether it is possible in the design definition of the custom control to determine WHAT is placed in the facet. And based on that display something different in the custom control. I imagine this may not be possible.

Comment: I must not have understood the question exactly. What you looking for might not be doable without looking into the Designer Tooling extensions that were adding in 8.5.3 so that IBM could add design definitions to the Extlib

Answer (score 0):

Dan,

Can you get the Editable Area as a javax.faces.component.UIComponent and then do .getFacets()?

BTW, hope you're well!